# Forming a sequence of css selectors as argument to pup to get particular value from javadoc html

Tags: css

It isn't often that I attempt to implement something that attempts to integrate three different languages (four, if you count bash), sort of.

I want to write a little tool that scans the HTML files in the Java JDK javadoc package, focusing on blocks like the following:

```
<dl>
<dt><span class="simpleTagLabel">Since:</span></dt>
<dd>1.8</dd>
</dl>
```

I want to get the "1.8" value out of this.

So, I figured I would find a command-line tool that can parse HTML and figure out how to extract this.

I found the "[pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup)" tool (which is written in "go"), and it seems to be close, but I now have to figure out the correct sequence of CSS selectors to get to this element.  I've tried several variations, but nothing that really is doing what I need.

**Update**:

The answer from Sølve Tornøe comes close, and in fact I can implement somewhat of a kludge to get the data I want.

If I just use `'dl dt + dd'`, it gives me a lot of elements that match that pattern.  Ideally, I wish I could do something like `'dl dt (> span[class="simpleTagLabel"]) + dd'`, where the "> span ..." thing is used for matching, but having it "pop back up" after matching the span, so it can look for peers of "dt".  I imagine there's no way to do this in CSS.

My big kludge workaround is to assume that all of my real candidate elements have the text "1." in them.  With that big assumption, I can use `'dl dt + dd:contains("1.")'`.  This at least works with the data I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `>`(child) `+`(Adjacent sibling) `element`(dl tag..) to the following combination:

`dl > dt + dd`

This translates to: Give me the element that is a `dd` tag and is an Adjacent sibling of `dt` that also is a child of `dl`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('dl > dt + dd').innerText)
```

```css
dl > dt + dd {
 color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt><span class="simpleTagLabel">Since:</span></dt>
  <dd>1.8</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: and why not simply `dd` ? or `dl dd` ?

Comment: That is, of course, the easiest way indeed! I just assumed he wanted the most specific selector possible, giving him the most accurate results.

Comment: Well, yes, ideally I want a single selector chain, which processed on a single HTML file, gets the exact element I want. I'll update the question with a little more clarification based on this answer.

Comment: I see. Well, as far as I know, one cannot create a selector that checks for another element's children while still being a sibling (The example you added in the edit) **YET** - I just subbed uppon [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) which is in working draft of selectors lvl 4. Looks like that could theoretically solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use XPath instead of css selectors, you can easily step up through parent nodes of matched elements. This can be done with the perl [XML::XPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) command line tool, or [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html):

```
$ xpath -q -e "//dt/span[contains(@class,'simpleTagLabel')]/../../dd/text()" < test.html
1.8

$ xmllint --xpath "//dt/span[contains(@class,'simpleTagLabel')]/../../dd/text()" test.html
1.8
```

Comment: This strategy might work, if I was using xml-compliant HTML. Both xmllint and xpath get errors because of this. Now I guess I'll have to figure out "tidy", which isn't being obvious to me.